# Python: Beautifulsoup returning None or [ ]

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

hello im practicing my requests and web scraping skills, so im attempting to scrape the trending page on youtube, and pull the title of the videos that are trending, which is this link [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending)

this is the code im running

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending'
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
a = soup.find_all("a", {"id": "video-title"})
print(a)
```

and its returning [], i dont understand why its returning [] when its the in the source code,

Comment: As mentioned in all the answers below, the content is dynamic and it can't be retrieved with `requests`. Usually, we can reverse-engineer the JavaScript code, but usually it's not worth the effort, and it's easier to use `selenium`.

Answer (score 2):

print the contents of the variable `html.content` - does it contain that ID?

My bet is no, youtube.com is a heavily javascript dependant website, but the `requests` module doesn't have a js engine. What your browser sees usually isn't what a module like `requests` sees.

Comment: is there any other way to do it instead of selenium? like a more requests like way?

Answer (score 2):

You may need a method like selenium which allows time for page to fully render. The following currently yields 70 titles.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending'

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)
titles = [title.text for title in WebDriverWait(d,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#video-title")))]
print(titles)
d.quit()
```

Comment: is there any other way to do it instead of selenium? like a more requests like way?

Comment: You can add headless argument to avoid appearance of browser

Comment: how do i tell if a site is using javascript opposed to just html,?

Comment: You can switch off javsascript in browser and compare response against with js enabled

Comment: If the page updates when you interact with it as well.

Answer (score 2):

The web is devolving in that it's becoming increasingly inscrutable. "Modern" webpages, for the most part, are no longer generated by the server as the user will see them; rather, globs of script are being sent to the user and basically injecting whatever ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ into the DOM.

That's why you'll need to use Selenium bindings with a full-blown browser, as mentioned by QHarr above.

My apologies for not making this a comment, but apparently I need 50 points to do that.

Comment: is there any other way to do it instead of selenium? like a more requests like way?

Comment: Well, Python has a library for everything, so there's probably an alternative to Selenium, but it would probably end up doing pretty much the same thing: either emulating a full-blown browser, or controlling a full-blown browser. Fortunately, there's a way to use Selenium in which the browser is "headless", meaning that it won't actually intrude into the GUI in your OS, i.e. you won't have to have a popup window. It's been a while, but I think the way I used it last was with a specially built version of Chromium.

Comment: how do i tell if a site is using javascript opposed to just html,?

Comment: That's a difficult question to answer, because there's really no way of observing it directly. I would say that as a rough guide you can probably infer whether a site is "using Javascript" (in the manner of a [single-page app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) (SPA)) if a library like Python Requests doesn't work. There are other signs you can look for: if the website seems to load in a piecemeal fashion (especially noticeable on Youtube), or, in your browser's Web Inspector, if the index.html doesn't seem to contain much of anything and references a large JS bundle.