# Whats the problem with my code it prints none when I use find() method and when I use findAll() method it prints empty array?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

yt_link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKDdT_nyP54"

response = requests.get(yt_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
title = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'style-scope ytd-app'})
print(title)
```

It prints empty array `[]`, and if I use `find()` method then it prints `None` as a result.

Why does this happen. Please help me I am stuck here.

Comment: Without testing I bet it's one of those things are loaded via javascript and you need Selenium. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53980890/python-beautifulsoup-returning-none-or).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its difficult to find title because of youtube uses javascript and dynamic content rendering so what you can do try to print `soup` first and find title from it,so in meta you can find title extract it. And it work for any URL probably

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

yt_link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKDdT_nyP54"

response = requests.get(yt_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find('meta',attrs={"name":"title"})
print(title.get("content"))
```

output:

```
Akon - Smack That (Official Music Video) ft. Eminem
```

Answer (score 0):

As find() method returns the first matching object if it doesn't find then returns None and findAll() method returns the list of matching object if it doesn't find then returns empty list.